# Scroll to img inside a div with overflow-x

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have an image gallery with one main picture and a bunch of thumbnails. I have a prev & next button.

The thumbnails are inside a div with overflow-x set to scroll. It looks like this (with more than 3 pictures):

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="pic1" /></li>
        <li><img src="pic2" /></li>
        <li><img src="pic3" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click on "Next", I would like to scroll the div to the selected thumbnail.

Is there anyway I can do that with Javascript?

Comment: please make an attempt first yourself, then paste code issues here..please read the faq.

Comment: [Element.scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollLeft).

Comment: @Dory - What makes you think I haven't attempted? Cut this stupid crap of voting people down because they ask a valid question.

at Teemu - Thanks. I tried that on the ul and it didn't work, but when I tried on the div it works. thanks a lot.

Comment: @IIS7Rewrite many people post code here, and do not show an attempt to code themselves, no need to get upset. if you paste your attempt it would be easier for us to help you with this..

Comment: @Dory, I understand what you're saying, but my code was not much. I didn't know scrollLeft existed, so I was playing with css to set margin left. Obviously that wasn't the right approach, so all I needed was the correct call in Javascript.

All I"m saying is don't be so strict on people who ask a valid question. Voting down was completely unnecessary.